# what's the best way to increment a list of numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list like this x=[1,2,2,3,1,2,1,1,2,2] where the number is a positive integer that increments by 0 or 1 and sometimes resets to 1, and need to transform it to [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8] in an incremental way, where each 1 should be the previous number plus 1 and whatever follows 1 increment accordingly. Is there a simple way to do this via a numpy array etc? I tried using loops but I guess there's a simpler way.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use np.add.accumulate():

```
import numpy as np

x  = np.array([1,2,2,3,1,2,1,1,2,2])

x[1:] += np.add.accumulate(x[:-1]*(x[1:]==1))

print(x)

[1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8]
```